# Views dynamic date

Tags: views, datetime

I am trying to setup a view which will return a single nodes data. The idea is only one story type will be created per day.

My view is filtering on "node type: story" and "node:published". As an argument, I have "node:created date". I set it to "provide default argument" and then selected "current date".

Then idea is for the story node for today to be the sole result of the view. And at the stroke of midnight, the view should provide the next day's node or be empty if no such node has been created.

My probel is the view show the current dates node but at midnight, and beyond, I keep getting the same node rather than the next one.

please assist if you are able and I thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a views caching problem. If this is the most recent version of views, click the "Advanced Arrow" then under other click "caching" and select "time based". Set the desired   amount (not sure why 1 day isn't there, but as long as you do it at the right time, "6 hours" should be fine for both.

If that doesn't work, you can look into disabling caching completely under the views settings tab (serious performance hit), or writing something custom in cron to clear the views cache.